# Problem with counting the limit $ \lim _{x\rightarrow- \infty}\frac{x}{x+2\sqrt{(x^2-3))}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have problem with two limits:
$$
 \lim _{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x}{x+2 \sqrt{(x^2-3))}}
$$
 and
$$ 
\lim _{x\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{x}{x+2\sqrt{(x^2-3)}}.
$$
So i count the first limit:
$$
\lim _{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{x+2\sqrt{(x^2-3)}}= \lim _{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x}{x+2x\sqrt{(1-\frac{3}{x^2})}}= \lim _{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{1+2\sqrt{(1-\frac{3}{x^2})}}
$$

I see that $\frac{3}{x^2}\to0$ so my whole limit will be equal to $\frac{1}{3}$ And that is okay.

I do the same kind of transformation for $x\rightarrow-\infty$ and get $\frac{1}{3}$ too. I do not understand where is the difference. (The correct limit for $x\rightarrow-\infty$ is -1. I will be glad for any help).

Comment: Think about it this way: As $x \to \pm \infty$, $\sqrt{(x^2-3)} = x$. So essentially, the first expression is equal to $\frac{x}{x + 2x} = \frac{1}{3}$, and the second expression is equal to $\frac{-x}{-x + 2x} = -1$. Not a very rigorous argument, but it may help you understand it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\large \lim _{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x}{x+2\sqrt{(1-\frac{3}{x^2})}}\\
=\large \lim _{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x}{x+2|x|\sqrt{(1-\frac{3}{x^2})}}\\
=\large \lim _{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{1-2\sqrt{(1-\frac{3}{x^2})}}$$
Since $x$ is negative as $x$ goes to $-\infty$ and so $|x|=-x$

Answer (score 3):

As $\;x\to-\infty\;$ we can assume $\;x<0\;$ , so

$$\frac x{x+2\sqrt{x^2-3}}\cdot\frac{\frac1x}{\frac1x}=\frac{1}{1-2\sqrt{1-\frac3{x^2}}}\xrightarrow[x\to-\infty]{}-1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{x}{x+2\sqrt{x^2-3}} = \lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{1}{1+2\frac{|x|}{x}\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x^2}}}
$$
therefore you have two different results: $1/3$ and $-1$ respectively!